# Custom Sort order PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have these 2 columns in the table and my PHP code on my site is connected to it.

`username | primary_group`

I currently have it being sorted by `username` but how would I make it sort by `primary_group` with the groups in a certain order without making a sort column in the group name table and link the tables?

**Currently, I have:**

`SELECT username, primary_group FROM table_name ORDER BY username`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use MySQL's `ORDER BY FIELD` capability to specify a certain custom order to use when sorting on `primary_group`:

```
SELECT
    username, primary_group
FROM
    table_name
ORDER BY
    FIELD(primary_group, 'group1', 'group2', 'group3', ...)
```